# MongoDB: reverse regex search?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Given this object

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sku" : "abc123" }
```

I can use this regex to find it

```
db.products.find( { sku: { $regex: /^abc/ } } )
```

**But how can I do the reverse?**

Given this object

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sku" : "abc" }
```

and if the user input is `abc123`, how can I find the object with `abc`?

`db.products.find(` ??? `)`

Comment: Eh... duplicate title or duplicate question? That post doesn't answer my question...

Comment: it's actually the same basic question, with the same solution of using `$where` to perform the regex match:  `{$where: "'abc123'.match(new RegExp('^' + this.sku))"}`

Answer (score -1):

Here you cand find a lot of information about mongo to SQL conversion,
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE sku like "%abc%"

db.users.find( { sku: { $regex: /abc/ } )

this is the only thing you can do, you can't search for something if it doesn't match the correct parameters, abc!= abc123 it's clear, it's like if you search in youtube radioactive, and the first result is a radio...  in any case check some regexp expresions which may help you ;)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: and i don't see enougth investigation by your part.. please.. search a little before asking here... it's not a free homework maker...